# Output Multiple CSV files to browser in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, csv

I have a large large table of data (in mongodb) with more than 5 million rows. I want to export the data to csv and output the csv in browser directly. I am using PHP.

For smaller record set less than a million rows, the following code works perfectly.

```
set_time_limit(0);
$output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=auditresults_$i.csv"); 
fputcsv($output, array('id','createdon','colum1','column2','column3','colum4'));                             
foreach ($items as $item) {               
     fputcsv($output, $item)                 
}            
fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");
```

However, when I export large data sets such as 5 million rows, the above code fails.

I want to see if there is a way to split the above results in batches of 100,000 rows and output multiple csv files through the browser.

Comment: Each request can serve only a single response (1 html page, or 1 image, or 1 pdf, or 1 csv file, or 1 zip file)

Comment: You are missing a semicolon (inside the `foreach` loop). Also, where does `$items` come from? And how is MongoDB relevant here?

Comment: Sverri MongoDB was mentioned here to find if there is any other alternative method to export data to csv through PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send a single response to a request.

The solution could be to output multiple csv files in a temporary folder on your website, and send the downloadable url links to those files as a response.